# ViewDidAppear is not being called

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidappear

I'm using a delegate `UITabbarController` with transition animation like this:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSArray *tabViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers;
    UIView * fromView = tabBarController.selectedViewController.view;
    UIView * toView = viewController.view;
    if (fromView == toView)
        return TRUE;
    NSUInteger fromIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:tabBarController.selectedViewController];
    NSUInteger toIndex = [tabViewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

    [UIView transitionFromView:fromView
                    toView:toView
                  duration:0.3
                   options: toIndex > fromIndex ? UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    if (finished) {
                        tabBarController.selectedIndex = toIndex;
                    }
    }];
    return true;
}
```

Only this broke my entire `ViewDidAppear` on the views. I'm resetting the `UIWebView` to the homepage when switching between tabs, but this doesn't work anymore. Any suggestions? Here's my `VieDidLoad`:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    _progressProxy = [[NJKWebViewProgress alloc] init];
    _webView.delegate = _progressProxy;
    _progressProxy.webViewProxyDelegate = self;
    _progressProxy.progressDelegate = self;

    [self loadSite];
    [TestFlight passCheckpoint:@"Bekijkt homepage"];
}
```

`[self loadSite];` is defined as:

```
-(void)loadSite
{
    NSString *dealerurl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name_preference"];
    NSString *urlAddress= @"http://www.sportdirect.com/shop/";
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress]];
    [_webView loadRequest:req];
    [[_webView scrollView] setBounces: NO];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code looks OK, set a Breakoint in viewDidAppear and try to replace your viewDidAppear methode with viewWillAppear

Comment: @DavidG. Turns out it actually reaches the breakpoint set on `self loadsite` every switch.. It's just not changing the `UIWeview`..

Comment: OK, set a breakpoint at the first line of -(void)loadSite, and check values, check if something is nil. And I would add this methode to recognize if the webView did fail to load: - (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    
    NSLog(@"Error");
}

Comment: `_webView UIWebView * nil 0x00000000` _webView is... How to get rid of it?

Comment: When will that error occur? I would recogmend to replace all _propertyNamen with self.propertyName, like replacing _webView with self.webView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
[_webView loadRequest:req];
```

to this:

```
self.webView loadRequest:req;
```

I think this will undo the `nil`.